# Is there any protocol or API for iot device communication over wi-fi?

Tags: networking, iot

I have been trying to write a program for a Debian based IoT device and now i need it to communicate with another device within the Wi-Fi network without relying on the cloud. 
Is there an existing library, or protocol that enables local network communication between two or more devices?

Comment: A simple TCP/UDP server client application can be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT and AMQP are two typical protocols that pop into my mind, but HTTP and WebSockets are very common as well. But there is an absolutely overwelming amount of possible protocols you could choose from. I'd probably go with the Web of Things standard: https://iot.mozilla.org/

This picture shows a few protocols that Web of Things apparently utilizes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think UDP and or TCP work well for this.